# Adding a public class to click using xpath with Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create a public class to click an item on a webpage with selenium by just passing it the xpath and driver I'm using.  I want to be able to just do:

```
ClickByXpath(driver, "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[1]");
```

Here's the code I'm using, but it's complaining that the method xpath string is not applicable:

```
package TestPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // Go to google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        //click in the searchbox
        ClickByXpath(driver, "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[1]");
    }   
        public static void ClickByXpath(WebDriver [] driverUsed , String[] XPath_to_click) throws Exception {
            driverUsed.findElement(By.xpath(XPath_to_click)).click();
        }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering why are you passing arrays of both types while only one instance can be used at a time?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm just starting with this so am undoubtedly doing it wrong. Are they arrays because I've used square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a String:

```
ClickByXpath(driver, "/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[1]");
```

But you method signature says that you should pass a String **Array**:

```
public static void ClickByXpath(WebDriver [] driverUsed , String[] XPath_to_click)
```

Same problem with your driver! If you change the signature and remove the Arrays, you should be good:

```
public static void ClickByXpath(WebDriver driverUsed , String XPath_to_click)
```

Please note that this has nothing to do with Selenium, this is (very?) basic Java programming. You should consider getting some help with learning at least basics of programming first.